# Reference for the product of falling factorials?

Tags: combinatorics

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Connection_coefficients_and_identities), the following identity for the product of falling factorials is given without any citation:
$$
(x)_m (x)_n = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} k! \cdot (x)_{m + n - k},
$$
where $(x)_m := x (x - 1) (x - 2) ... (x - m + 1)$.

Does anyone know a reference that explicitly states this formula?

---

Note: I've looked at Graham-Knuth-Patashnik (Concrete Mathematics), without success.

Answer (score 1):

I found the formula (written in an alternative form) in Corollary 8 of the following paper:
Rosas, M. H. 2002. Specializations of MacMahon symmetric functions and the polynomial algebra. vol. 246. Formal power series and algebraic combinatorics (Barcelona, 1999)

Comment: Also, Proposition 14 in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308536/is-this-sum-of-cycles-invertible-in-mathbb-qs-n/308601 .